# Process files with m4 in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

as a part of build process I need to process some files with m4. These files are given an '.in' extension and are located not only in the top-level dir, but also in subdirs.
I locate them using find and process them in a shell loop.

Is there some makefile syntax magic to write simpler rule to process them save the output into a file (the '.in' extension stripped) in the same directory as the input file?

This is what I have in my makefile now:

```
PROCESS_FILES=$(shell find . -name \*.in)
WORK_FILES=$(subst .in,,$(PROCESS_FILES))



$(WORK_FILES): $(PROCESS_FILES) 
  for file in $(PROCESS_FILES); \
  do \
      m4  $$file > $${file%.*};\
  done
```

Comment: The answer is probably yes, but some of us are not familiar with m4. Could you show the (minimal) makefile you use now?

Comment: Hi, I added the relevant section of my current makefile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a set of rules to convert files with the suffix `.in` to files without that suffix.

In the classic notation, that would be something like:

```
# Not functional — see discussion
.SUFFIXES: .in       # Add .in as a suffix

M4       = m4
M4FLAGS  =
M4SCRIPT = xyz.m4

.in:
    ${M4} ${M4FLAGS} ${M4SCRIPT} $< > $*
```

This adds `.in` as a recognized suffix, and says that you convert the file with a `.in` suffix to the file without it using the command specified by the three macros.  The `$<` is the name of the file with the `.in` extension; the `$*` is the name of the file without the extension.

Unfortunately though, that notation only works when the files to be converted have names such as `xyz.in` and need to be converted to `xyz`.  It does not work for a case where `xyz.h.in` needs to be converted to `xyz.h`.

It would be possible to specify that the suffixes are `.h.in` and `.h`, but then the rule for converting between the two starts with `.h.in.h:` and `make` gets confused.

However, GNU make has an alternative notation for defining suffix rules which can accommodate this:

```
.SUFFIXES: .h.in .h      # Add .h.in and .h as suffixes

M4       = m4
M4FLAGS  =
M4SCRIPT = xyz.m4

%.h: %.h.in
    ${M4} ${M4FLAGS} ${M4SCRIPT} $< > $*.h
```

The `%.h: %.h.in` line is able to deal with the suffix with two dots.  The only nuisance is that for each extension such as `.c.in` or `.y.in` or `.mk.in`, you have to provide similar mappings.

(Tested on Mac OS X 10.7.4.  If that makefile is `xyz.mk`, you can create an empty file `xyz.h.in` and then run `make -n -f xyz.mk xyz.h` and you'll see the build would run the command `m4  xyz.m4 xyz.h.in > xyz.h`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a source file `path/to/file.in`, a rule for making `%` from `%.in`, and a dependency on the output file `path/to/file`, that should be all you need.

Perhaps you want to express your dependencies in terms of the output from `find`. In GNU Make this is easy; in other dialects, perhaps you want to generate and include something like `find -name '*.in' | sed 's/\.in$//' >make.dep`